# ENVI: Postclassification, remove pixels of certain size

Tags: remote-sensing, classification, envi

I did a classification over multiple Landsat imagery in ENVI 5.1, which turned out not too bad (ice and snow in Cyan in the picture below). Now I am about to do a postclassification to filter out pixel values which I don't want in my classification (in my case small ice bergs and snow patches) to smoothen the results.

Is there a tool in ENVI where I could define the number of pixels which should be eliminated? What I have in mind is to get rid of all areas which are smaller than let's say for example 1 km2.

How would you do this? Is there an easy way in ENVI? I've tried the `Sieve Classes` tool and also `Majority/Minority Analysis` tools up until now but I would be interested what you normally use to do this kind of thing, when area definition is important?

Comment: Although this link relates to different software, there is a lot of good advice here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/41064/8104