# Delineating boundary around many small polygons to reduce number of polygons but retain relative coverage using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: shapefile, polygon, merge, dissolve

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.3 with an Advanced license.

I ran the slope tool on a DEM and converted the resulting raster into a shapefile with two polygons, one with slopes > 40% grade and the other with slopes <=40% grade. This creates many polygons across the area I am looking at. I am wondering if there is a way to create an outline/boundary that encompasses the small boundaries, but retains the general shape.

[image: image 1] [image: Image 2]

In the pictures above the black rectangles are the small polygons I am talking about. In the second image the blue boundary is what I am trying to create. Ultimately I'd like this blue boundary to be a polygon. The goal of this is to reduce the number of polygons and the size of the shapefile. (I have already used the dissolve tool).

Comment: Check into convex / concave hull tools...

Comment: You may want to have a look at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41064/performing-raster-noise-reduction-and-edge-smoothing/225193#225193

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using an *Advanced* licensed ArcMap then you could look into using the [Aggregate Polygons](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/cartography-toolbox/aggregate-polygons.htm) tool. This will achieve your desired output.