# Aggregate disjoint polygons

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon

I need to aggregate disjoint polygons within a certain distance in ArcGIS but it seems that the perfect command to do it, **Aggregate Polygons**, is only available with an ArcInfo that I don't have.

Would you know whether there's another way to do this with another command?

Below is a sample of two polygons to be merged.

**NOTES**:

1. the usual method using Editor will not work because it's many polygons
2. Resampling using Majority will not only do either because it increases the area of the polygon too much.

[image]

Comment: Start editing, select the two polygons, in the editor drop-down menu, select 'Merge'.  This answers your question as asked, but I am assuming you want an automated process.  Maybe add some more detail to your question.

Comment: Hi @jbalk thanks. Yes, it's many polygons, so doing it one by one will not do unfortunately...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to keep the original shapes as making them multipart if the distance condition holds, the steps below may help:

1. Buffer your polygons by the half of the distance threshold that you
   want to use (*certain distance* in your question)
2. Dissolve the result of the previous as single part
3. Buffer again but this time negate the distance (this will leave the
   connecting features based on your threshold)
4. Add a new field, say GROUP_ID, and copy OBJECTID field values across
5. Use spatial join by using your original features as target and the
   negative buffered polygons as join features
6. Dissolve again, this time using GROUP_ID field as the dissolve field
   and leaving Multipart option ticked.

Comment: Thanks @fatih_dur, would there be any way to aggregate the polygons in less steps?

Comment: As far as *I* know this is the way (based on my assumption), but you can wait for other people to answer. I check out the Aggregate Polygon tool and the output exemplified there is a bit different than your intention. In fact my approach is inspired from [another question in GIS SE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41064/performing-raster-noise-reduction-and-edge-smoothing).

Comment: OK, maybe resampling/majority to a larger cell size would make the connections...?